# Permission denied while executing binaries in tmp folder (Docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello I am trying to build an image which can compile and run a c++ program securely.

```
FROM golang:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN env CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /worker

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache g++ && apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=builder worker /bin

ARG USER=default
RUN addgroup -S $USER && adduser -S $USER -G $USER

USER $USER

ENTRYPOINT [ "worker" ]
```

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  gpp:
    build: .
    environment:
      - token=test_token
      - code=#include <iostream>\r\n\r\nusing namespace std;\r\n\r\nint main() {\r\n   int a = 10;\r\n   int b = 20;\r\n   cout << a << \" \" << b << endl;\r\n   int temp = a;\r\n   a = b;\r\n   b = temp;\r\n   cout << a << \" \" << b << endl;\r\n   return 0;\r\n}
    network_mode: bridge
    privileged: false
    read_only: true
    tmpfs: /tmp
    security_opt:
      - "no-new-privileges"
    cap_drop:
      - "all"
```

Here **worker** is a golang binary which reads **code** from environment variable and stores it in **/tmp** folder as **main.cpp**, and then tries to compile and run it using `g++ /tmp/main.cpp` && `./tmp/a.out` (using golang exec)

I am getting this error `scratch_4-gpp-1 | Error : fork/exec /tmp/a.out: permission denied`, from which what I can understand / know that executing anything from tmp directory is restricted.

Since, I am using read_only root file system, I can only work on tmp directory, Please guide me how I can achieve above task keeping my container secured.

Comment: My only idea would be to mount other tmpfs with exec, start the container as root, compile your program, then drop the privileges with su to a user to run the program, and that user should have readonly permission to the tmpfs mounted with exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's [default options for a tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#tmpfs-mount-tmpfs-filesystems) include `noexec`.  `docker run --tmpfs` allows an extended set of mount options, but neither Compose [`tmpfs:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#tmpfs) nor the extended syntax of [`volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-3) allows changing anything other than the size option.

One straightforward option here is to use an anonymous volume.  Syntactically this looks like a normal `volumes:` line, except it only has a container path.  The `read_only:` option will make the container's root filesystem be read-only, but volumes are exempted from this.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  ...
    read_only: true
    volumes:
      - /build # which will be read-write
```

This will be a "normal" Docker volume, so it will be disk-backed and you'll be able to see it in `docker volume ls`.

Comment: Yes this does work, I can write my files in build directory, but it's not letting me compile my source code using `g++ -o /build/a.out /build/main.cpp` throwing an error `Cannot create temporary file in ./: Read-only file system`

Comment: I solved the remaining issue after short debugging, can you please update your answer with detailed explanation of steps I performed. Please refer my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Complete summary of solution -

@davidmaze mentioned to add an anonymous volume using

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  ...
    read_only: true
    volumes:
      - /build # which will be read-write
```

as I replied I am still getting an error `Cannot create temporary file in ./: Read-only file system` when I tried to compile my program. When I debugged my container to see file system changes in `read_only:false` mode, I found that compiler is trying to save the `a.out` file in `/bin` folder, which is suppose
to be read only.

So I added this additional line before the entry point and my issue was solved.

```
FROM golang:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN env CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /worker

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache g++ && apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=builder worker /bin

ARG USER=default
RUN addgroup -S $USER && adduser -S $USER -G $USER

USER $USER

WORKDIR /build <---- this line

ENTRYPOINT [ "worker" ]
```